# Button 'onclick' doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, spring, button, onclick

I'm testing a web application with spring MVC 3 and I'm facing an error that I can't resolve.

I have a controller that gives me a list of data from the DB that is handled in the JSP with a forEach statement.
Also, inside the `forEach` i have a form that will be displayed in a `jquery-ui dialog` after clicking a button.

My JSP looks like this:

```
<html>
/**
*
*
**/
<c:forEach items="${listaFecha}" var="fec">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${fec.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${fec.NOM_ASUNTO}" /></td>
                <td><fmt:formatDate value="${fec.FEC_INICIO}" pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY" /></td>
                <td><fmt:formatDate value="${fec.FEC_FIN}" pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${fec.PERIODO}" /></td>
                <td><button id="faqIE${fec.id}" value="${fec.id}" onclick="changeFec(${fec.id})">Editar</button></td>
            </tr>
            <div id="edit-form${fec.id}" class="edit" style="text-align:center;" title="Editar Fecha">      </br>   
                <form name="fechasE" method="POST" target="_parent" action="<c:url value="/manage/insertaForm"/>" id="form2E${fec.id}">
                    <label style="margin-right:133px;">Tipo de Solicitud: </label></br>
                    <input type="text" class="fields" name="asE" value="${fec.NOM_ASUNTO}" disabled/></br>

                    <label style="margin-right:158px;">Fecha Inicial: </label> </br>    
                    <input type="text" class="fields" name="date1E" value="<fmt:formatDate value="${fec.FEC_INICIO}" pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY"/>" /></br>

                    <label style="margin-right:165px;">Fecha Final: </label></br>
                    <input type="text" class="fields" name="date2E" value="<fmt:formatDate value="${fec.FEC_FIN}" pattern="dd-MMM-YYYY"/>" /></br>

                    <label style="margin-right:185px;">Periodo: </label></br>
                    <input type="text" class="fields" name="pdE" value="${fec.PERIODO}"/></br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
/**
*
*
**/
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeFec(n) {
    $( "#edit-form"+n ).dialog({     
            autoOpen: true,      
            height: 390,      
            width: 350,      
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {        
                Editar: function() {
                        $( "form2E"+n ).submit();
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );          
                },        
                Cancelar: function() {          
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );        
                }      
            }        
        });
}
</script>
```

It work fine in Opera, Google Chrome and Firefox but in IE7,8,9 doesn't.
I don't know why! I've been searching for hours without success! I hope somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT**:

This is how it have to work http://jsfiddle.net/NbddB/22/ .
But the value in `changeFec(value)` have to be dinamic and the divs are created dynamically inside the `forEach` statement.

Comment: shows the rest of the code please or do a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question! Sorry if someone lost time trying to help me, i really aprecciate it.

The problem was that I didn't give you enough information about my problem..inside the table (where my form was included) I'm using tablesorter with tablesorterPager plugin and that was the problem. It seems that tablesorterPager doesn't like too much my form in jquery-ui dialog :(

Well, the only thing i did was putting my form outside the table and then everything worked just fine in every browser! =)

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
    toggleExpand(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (!this.state.expanded) {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
        } else {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
        }

        this.setState({
            expanded: !this.state.expanded
        });
    }

    handleOutsideClick(e) {
        if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
            return;
        }

        this.toggleExpand(e);
    }

    toggleOpen(e) {   
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

render() {
  return (
                    {this.state.expanded && (
                            <div
                                className={styles.pointer}
                            >
                                <div
                                    onClick={this.toggleOpen}

                                >
                                    <button
                                        onClick={this.toggleExpand}
                                        className={[
                                            styles.close}
                                        alt="Close Button"

                                    />

                                    <div
                                        className={
                                            styles.pop}
                                     >
                                        <div>
                                            <span className={styles.label}>
                                            abcd 
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )}

)}
```